# Copy from Multiple Excel Files (dynamic ranges) and Paste in master Sheet (Dynamic range)

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic, range

Can you please hep me with this code. I want to transfer data from multiple files to one master sheet. I am getting error in last but one line of the code

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()
Dim MyFile As String
Dim erow
Dim Filepath As String
Filepath = "C:\Users\Nadeem\Desktop\2013\2G\"
MyFile = Dir(Filepath)
Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
If MyFile = "zmaster.xlsm" Then      'zmaster is the master file in same folder
Exit Sub
End If

Workbooks.Open (Filepath & MyFile)
Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection.End(xlToRight), Selection.End(xlDown)).Copy   'Copy Dynamic range
'ActiveWorkbook.Application.CutCopyMode = False
'ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

Application.Workbooks("zmaster.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate 'Added this line
erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row   'Paste in Dynamic Range
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 1).Address)

MyFile = Dir

Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try commenting out or deleting the line shown:

```
Workbooks.Open (Filepath & MyFile)
Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection.End(xlToRight), Selection.End(xlDown)).Copy   'Copy Dynamic range
'ActiveWorkbook.Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Also, when you set the destination range `Cells(erow,1)` evaluates to its value (which is blank) instead of its address. So change that line to:

```
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 1).Address)
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error: Run-time Error '1004'. Can you guyz please help

Comment: See my edit. In addition to clearing the clipboard by setting `CutCopyMode = False` there was an error in setting the Paste destination

Comment: I tried the code below and it is working now. Only problem is i am not able to close the excel files from where i am copying the data. I want all the files to close and only master sheet to remain open. Please see the changes above

Comment: @Nadeem the reason your source workbooks aren't closing is that you have commented out `ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False`. Uncomment that line and that problem should be solved. You will also need to re-insert the Paste command `ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 1).Address)`

Comment: @ Frank, Firstly thanx mate for your help. When i uncomment that line it is giving me too much data on clipboard and when i say no, it gives me error. If yes then it copies the data

Comment: @Nadeem add `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` before the `ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False` command and reset after using `Application.DisplayAlerts = True`

Comment: Thanx Mate, you are a star. I give your answer a thumbs up :)

Comment: @Nadeem, I'm glad we got there in the end. When coding, try stepping through your code using **F8** and monitor your variables via the **Locals** or **Immediate** panes. Setting **Watches** can also be useful.